# Component to string in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, components, type-conversion, lazarus

I made program according to these instructions.
Works great, but I do not know why.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/ComponentToString_(Delphi).

My code is:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  ExtCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Image1: TImage;
    Image2: TImage;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

function ComponentToStringProc(Component: TComponent): string;
var
  BinStream:TMemoryStream;
  StrStream: TStringStream;
  s: string;
begin
  BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    StrStream := TStringStream.Create(s);
    try
      BinStream.WriteComponent(Component);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      ObjectBinaryToText(BinStream, StrStream);
      StrStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= StrStream.DataString;
    finally
      StrStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    BinStream.Free
  end;
end;

function StringToComponentProc(Value: string): TComponent;
var
  StrStream:TStringStream;
  BinStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  StrStream := TStringStream.Create(Value);
  try
    BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ObjectTextToBinary(StrStream, BinStream);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= BinStream.ReadComponent(nil);
    finally
      BinStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    StrStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Text:= ComponentToStringProc(Image1);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var img:TImage;
begin
  img:= (StringToComponentProc(Memo1.Text) as TImage);
  img.Left:=200;
  img.Top:=96;
  img.Parent:=form1;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Height:=Image1.Height;
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Width:=Image1.Width;
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Rectangle(0,0,Image1.Width,Image1.Height);
end;
initialization

RegisterClass(TImage);
end.
```

My question is: Why do I have

```
initialization


RegisterClass (TImage);
```

When Image2 is a visual component placed on form1?

If there's two lines are missing, it says error 219 Invalid typecast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The streaming framework needs to be able to convert a component class name into a class. Once it has done so it is able to instantiate an object of the right class.

The key line of code is:

```
Result := BinStream.ReadComponent(nil);
```

Although `Result` has type `TComponent`, the actual runtime type can be a subclass of `TComponent`. In your case, `TImage`.

So, in order to be able to convert the string `'TImage'` into the meta class `TImage`, there needs to be a registry (i.e. a map) of classes and their names. And that registry is populated by calls to `RegisterClass`. Without that call, the streaming framework cannot find the metaclass `TImage` that is named `'TImage'`. And so it cannot stream in the component.

Although you are working with FPC, the Delphi [documentation for `RegisterClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.RegisterClass) will be helpful to you.